# Content is not being updated after revalidate time in Nextjs

Tags: javascript, next.js, vercel

I have a blog created with Nextjs and **hosted on Vercel** where I'm using Incremental Static Regeneration. I set the revalidate time to 60 seconds but when I update something in the database, If i'm not wrong after a request when revalidate time pass it should start rebuilding the page in the background so on the next requests the page would be updated, but that does not happen, even if I wait 10 minutes the content keep being the old, it does not look like a rebuild is happening at all, this is the code I am using on the mentioned page

```js
export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async ({ params }) => {

  const { id } = params;

  const result = await getPost(id?.toString()!);
  const parsed = await parseMarkdown(result.content);
  return {
    props: {
      post: result,
      md: parsed,
    },
    revalidate: 60,
  };
};

export const getStaticPaths: GetStaticPaths = async () => {
  const result = await getAllPosts();
  const paths = result.data.map((post) => {
    return {
      params: { id: post.id },
    };
  });
  return {
    paths,
    fallback: "blocking",
  };
};
```

Comment: Can you replicate the issue locally when running `next build && next start`?

Comment: @juliomalves I tried replicating the issue and it still persists while running locally using `next build && next start`

Comment: @juliomalves On my dev server everything is working perfectly but after building the project the new items added are left out.